# I keep getting errors of undefined bitfields on discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord

this is the error

```
ReferenceError: PermissionsBitField is not defined

at Object.execute (/home/runner/Nodejs-1/commands/kick.js:20:82)
at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Nodejs-1/index.js:25:23)
at Client.emit (node:events:514:28)
at InteractionCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/Nodejs-1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCr eate.js:97:12)
at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (/home/runner/Nodejs-1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/Nodejs-1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:355:31)
at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Nodejs-1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:239:12)
at WebSocketManager.emit (/home/runner/Nodejs-1/node_modules/@vladfrangu/async_event_emitter/dist/index.cjs:282:31)
at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Nodejs-1/node_modules/@discordjs/ws/dist/index.js:1173:51)
at WebSocketShard.emit (/home/runner/Nodejs-1/node_modules/@vladfrangu/async_event_emitter/dist/index.cjs:282:31)
```

Here is my code for kicking:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('kick')
        .setDescription('Kick a member')
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option.setName('user')
                .setDescription('The user to kick')
                .setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('reason')
                .setDescription('Reason for kicking')),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const user = interaction.options.getUser('user');
        const reason = interaction.options.getString('reason') || 'No reason provided';

if (!interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.member.id).permissions.has([PermissionsBitField.Flags.KickMembers, PermissionsBitField.Flags.BanMembers])) {

            return interaction.reply({ content: 'You do not have permission to use this command.', ephemeral: true });
        }

        if (!user) {
            return interaction.reply({ content: 'Please specify a user to kick.', ephemeral: true });
        }

        if (!user.kickable) {
            return interaction.reply({ content: 'This user cannot be kicked.', ephemeral: true });
        }

        await user.kick(reason);
        await interaction.reply({ content: `Successfully kicked ${user.tag}.`, ephemeral: true });
    },
};
```

I tried replacing from has to get in the bitfields line, I tried using FLAGS but I got the same error.

Comment: PermissionsBitField is undefined.  Do you import it somewhere?  `const { PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');` ?

Comment: Please include your code with defined bitfields. As someone already mentioned:
const { PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');